# Finding Distribution in R

Tags: r, bayesian, prior, distributions

I have a Bayesian Inference Question. My prior has a normal distribution and $f(x|\theta)$ also has a normal distribution.

Now, I want to get the distribution of $h(x)$ in R, where $h(x)$ is the denominator of the posterior distribution; the integral of likelihood and prior distribution.

**Question:** Is there any function or anything in R which could say whether $h(x) \sim \operatorname{Normal}(a,b)$, i.e, to what distribution it belongs?

Comment: There's no notation for Bayesian stats that's standard enough that we can be completely sure what $h$ is intended to be. What's $h(x)$ in this context? Are you talking about the posterior density for $\theta$ (which is a function of $\theta$, not a function of $x$), or something else?

Comment: Following Glen's comments, you need to provide the prior and the sampling densities in full details for the question to make sense. In any case, R does not provide the distribution of an arbitrary transform of a standard distribution. You can always approximate it by simulation.

Comment: h(x) here is the denominator of posterior distribution; the integral of likelihood and prior distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the "distr" package.  I don't know if it will do exactly what you want, but it does give distributions of combinations of other distributions.

Comment: thanx. i wil try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Another option in the realm of fitting distributions is the `fitdistrplus` package. It fits distributions and calculates metrics which can be used to compare fits.

There is some manually work involved as you have to give a distribution and run it several times with a different distribution each run. It doesn't auto-magically do the evaluation of which distribution is *best*. However, it doesn't provide several metrics and plots to help in making a decision.

Hopefully this can help you.